# Plants with nutritional requirements similar to Cannabis

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations, variety-selection

What are some short plants that preferably could be grown indoor which have similar nutritional requirements (in terms of N-P-K ratio, doses etc.) as Cannabis?

The purpose of this is testing a mineral fertilizer for Cannabis, without actually growing Cannabis as it is illegal in my country.

I was looking into [Cannabaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabaceae) family and found out that Hops are closely related. However, due to its size/height it won't be convenient to grow it at home. Also, I'm not sure if being in the same family implies similar nutritional needs.

Plus bonus for valuable/exotic plants.

Answer (score 1):

[Hemp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemp) is a variety of cannabis sativa that would have similar nutritional requirements. Any discussion of whether it is legal to grow where you live is out of scope for here

This [reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20191213123305/https://www.gov.mb.ca/agriculture/crops/production/hemp-production.html#fertility) from wikipedia recommends the following fertilizer requirements

> Hemp seed appears to be sensitive to seed-placed nitrogen fertilizer.
> It is recommended that the nitrogen be side-banded, mid-row-banded or
> banded in a separate operation.
>
> There has been some research conducted on phosphate fertility trials
> in hemp. The trials indicate a reasonable tolerance to seed placed
> phosphate. Under ideal growing conditions plant population and grain
> yield was not affected by increasing the rates of P2O5.  At the
> suggested rate of 34 to 45 kilograms/hectare and good growing
> conditions, damage is not expected to hemp seedlings.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Hemp is a variety of Cannabis so your answer doesn't actually answer my question. Whether someone wants to take into account the legality status or not is up to him/her.